# DocuSign: when using an embedded signer, reusing the same envelope if they click on "Finish later"

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an envelope to be signed using this code

```js
       envelopesApi.createRecipientView(reqArgs.accountId, envelopeId, {
            recipientViewRequest: viewRequest,
        });
```

The viewRequest here contains `clientUserId` parameter as we are embedding docusign inside our app. I am saving the envelope id that was created in one of our tables.

When the user has clicked on 'Finish later', can I use the same envelope that was created earlier to be sent via email? or should I create new envelope that will not have `clientUserId` parameter set in the `viewRequest`?

Also, if we have to recreate this envelope will we be charged for the first envelope? If we void it before signing.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the Envelope, so this will not consume from your plan monthly quota.

You just have to request the signing URL again if it's used or expired. You Don't to recreate the envelope.

Comment: My usecase is not to request the signing URL again. I want to send the envelope via email the second time. Not sure, how to make the same envelope that was created with signing URL to be sent via email.